# Android Canvas - Bounding Rect

Tags: android, canvas

I have a simple question. What is a clip bounding rect on a Canvas? Is it the rectangle that the Canvas takes in reference to the viewport? I.e. what the Canvas.getClipBounds returns?

Cannot find any better explanation to this...

Thanks

Comment: It's will return a rect that will have the size of the viewing area.